# ¿Cómo puedo asegurarme que Firebase se ejecuta antes que nada?

Tags: android, firebase

Me gustaría asegurarme que se ejecute el `onDataChange` de Firebase antes que nada de la aplicación, ya que necesito obtener unos datos para crear una `GridView` y si tarda mucho en obtener los datos de Firebase, me da error `NullPointerException`, ya que obtiene valores `null`.

¿Cómo podría asegurar la ejecución del Firebase primero y despues todo lo demás?

Comment: Alguien me indica si con un AsyncTask se puede arreglar? gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una clase que extienda de Application y hacer que se ejecute en primer lugar el código en esa clase, a partir de ahí ya puedes decidir si lanzar una pantalla de Splash y esperar a esos datos antes de mostrar la actividad principal.

Comment: Digamos que tengo el metodo en el onCreate de la SplashScreen para obtener el Firebase y luego se ejecuta el Thread que hace la funcion de Splash, pero no estoy seguro que funcione bien, creo que alguna vez puede fallar, gracias por tu interes